# Manager giving me cold shoulder since handing notice in

Tags: manager, notice-period

One of my managers is giving me the cold shoulder since I've handed my notice in. Also, keeps on making snarky remarks.

This feels extremely uncomfortable and awkward.

I would like, at least, that the new (snarky) comments stop - they are making me feel uncomfortable. What is the best way to handle this?

Comment: Do you want to try to get the manager to stop ignoring you, or just want to know how to get through the last couple weeks with a manager that's ignoring you? It's not like you have to put up with this behavior for very long.

Comment: It's bothering me.

Comment: Saying it's bothering you doesn't explain what you want out of the situation. Remember, questions need to have a [clear addressable goal](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2693/custom-off-topic-close-reasons-change/2696#2696).

Comment: How long is your notice ?

Comment: Handle what? Isn't handing in your notice means you're going to quit?

Comment: really ignore, but if you really want to try something then give your manager a compliment.

Comment: @Aserre one more month

Comment: You've given them your notice, you've finished your task. It's unfortunate that your manager is treating you like this and you could mention it to HR but I wouldn't react to what your manager says. Worst case scenario they're trying to get a reaction out of you.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere, without experiencing the situation firsthand, I don’t think it’s okay for us to judge what should or shouldn’t be a bothersome behavior. The OP wanting the behavior to stop is enough of a reason to believe the behavior is inappropriate.

Comment: Seems like doing nothing worked. Manager is being nicer to me now

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> What is the best way to handle?

You continue to act in a professional manner during your notice period and don't worry about how your soon to be former manager behaves.

Answer (score 5):

> What is the best way to handle?

Your best bet is to do the best job you can while your still there.  Also **document** as much about your tasks\responsibilities as you can so that the next guy has a starting point to pick up and go.  Provide this documentation to your boss on your final day.

Obviously you cannot control how your ex-manager behaves, so *don't sweat things you cannot control*.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes a manager may take someone quitting personally.   Or perhaps he would prefer to just focus his attention on those that will be with him long-term.

Were you friends with him?   Did you hang out together after work?   If not, what do you expect?    If you're not particularly close to him he may have just moved on and is more concerned with those he views as not being "short-timers".

Comment: We got along well, which is why this irritating

Comment: Don't confuse "get along well" with "we are friends".   Hate to say it, but work acquaintances are not the same as friends.     Some people are very friendly with a lot of people from 8-5 on weekdays.